# Configure .bash_profile on linux (CENTOS) for multiple ORACLE HOMEs

Tags: linux, oracle, oracle12c, centos5

I am using a server with CENTOS 5.11 and for different circumstances I need to use two versions of Oracle. I have already installed Oracle 10g successfully, however I want to install the 12c, in part to migrate my DB.

The problem is that I do not know how to configure the .bash_profile which is where the ORACLE_HOME is configured in the following way:

```
    ## Oracle Env Settings 
    export TMP=/tmp
    export TMPDIR=$TMP
    export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=oracle.localdomain
    export ORACLE_UNQNAME=MYDB  
    export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
    export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/VERSION/db_1
    export ORACLE_SID=MYDB
    export PATH=/usr/sbin:$PATH          
    export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
    export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
    export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
```

I have searched and in the documentation of Oracle only mention that to install another version just need to install it in another ORACLE_HOME. So, my question is, **how to add the new ORACLE_HOME in .bash_profile?** and likewise if I can use the same users and groups for the new installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent question!
I stumbled upon the following:

1. The [Ask Tom's solution](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:3167741500346545498):

In brief - use `DBCA` to configure the second installation (it will take care of those details for you and don't worry about the listener). This means that when you install the second DB, just store the files with the Universal Installer and then configure this with [DBCA](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10897/install.htm#ADMQS023).

2. This [solution over here](https://iggyfernandez.wordpress.com/2013/01/08/two-instances-with-the-same-oracle-sid/).

In brief - use soft links for the `ORACLE_SID` and `ORACLE_HOME`. It's really a long tutorial, so there's no meaning to paste it here.

3. My personal favorite - Go over Point1 :-).

Now seriously - if you need to make it only through the .bash_profile, just put some `if` statements in it or create some external scripts for the different databases and just source them, or make .bash_profile call them, when you source it.

To wrap it all up - always "install" the database by just storing the files, don't trust the installer. After deployment, run `DBCA` to configure the installation. In all cases it should take care of these configurations for you. In some cases, if not all, `DBCA` will actually set the same `ORACLE_HOME` and `ORACLE_SID` for both, but they will have different unique names, which you'll use to connect with sqlplus to start/stop them.
As far as I see - all the solutions gravitate around the same thing I just mention in the paragraph above.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Write two functions to switch between the two installations.

```
export SYS_PATH=$PATH
export TMP=/tmp
export TMPDIR=$TMP

## First Oracle Env Settings 
ora1 ()
{
  export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=oracle1.localdomain
  export ORACLE_UNQNAME=MYDB1
  export ORACLE_BASE=/u01/app/oracle
  export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/VERSION/db_1
  export ORACLE_SID=MYDB1
  export PATH=/usr/sbin:$SYS_PATH          
  export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
  export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
}

## Second Oracle Env Settings
ora2 ()
{
  export ORACLE_HOSTNAME=oracle2.localdomain
  export ORACLE_UNQNAME=MYDB2
  export ORACLE_BASE=/u02/app/oracle
  export ORACLE_HOME=$ORACLE_BASE/product/VERSION/db_2
  export ORACLE_SID=MYDB2
  export PATH=/usr/sbin:$SYS_PATH          
  export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:$PATH
  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib
  export CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib
}
```

Use your default:

```
ora1
```

And switch to another:

```
ora2
```

And switch back:

```
ora1
```

Answer (score 0):

.oraenv only imports Oracle Env. If there are other applications involved and needs to set the env accordingly; along with oracle env .bash_profile really helps.

Answer (score -1):

Just change the last two lines of /etc/oratab from N to Y to shift from database to another database... run.

**. oraenv** on command prompt **no need to worry about .bash_profile**

```
ora1:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:Y
ora2:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db_1:Y
```